# Magento - override block

Tags: php, magento, overriding

I trying to do an example of overriding a block. I thought I followed the instructions correctly, but nothing happens. Is there an error somewhere?

The block to be overwritten is **Mage_Page_Block_Html_Head**.
I do the rewrite of the block in config.xml:

```
<config>
   <blocks>
        <html>
            <rewrite>
                <head>Hello_Mymodule_Block_Head</head>
            </rewrite>
        </html>
    </blocks>    
 </config>
```

Then I create Head.php in: app - code - local - Hello - Mymodule - Block - Head.php.

I copy the getTitle method from the original Head.php into my new Head.php, then I just put in "die()" to see if it works:

```
class Hello_Mymodule_Block_Head extends Mage_Page_Block_Html_Head {
public function getTitle()
{
    die();
    if (empty($this->_data['title'])) {
        $this->_data['title'] = $this->getDefaultTitle();
    }
    return strtoupper(htmlspecialchars(html_entity_decode(trim($this->_data['title']), ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8')));
}}
```

Nothing happens, and I don't know how to search for the error. My module is active and working (it shows up in admin)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to rewrite block Mage_Page_Block_Html_Head but what you are trying to rewrite is Mage_Block_Html_Head which do not exist at all. 
change your confix xml to

```
<config>
   <blocks>
        <page>
            <rewrite>
                <html_head>Hello_Mymodule_Block_Head</html_head>
            </rewrite>
        </page>
    </blocks>    
 </config>
```

Comment: Fantastic, thanks! I didn't think "Page" was a block, since it contains the "blocks" folder. Do you know the logic behind this? Is "Page" a block even though it is outside of blocks folder?

Comment: Page is the module name and you are rewriting block head which is under html folder.